# Check whether notification with same id exist or not?

Tags: android, notifications

> i want to identify whether a notification with id 1 is already there in notification bar or not ? if it's not then do some activity else display error ! Is it possible ? how ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do exactly what you're asking to do (based on id). Once you post the notification, you've lost your reference to whether the user has dismissed it, or it is still there. There are a couple of things you could do, but they're hacks that aren't going to be reliable or resilient. Perhaps if you could elaborate a little on why, or what specifically you're trying to accomplish (overall), it would be possible to provide more help.

Comment: I am developing an app in which user can download files. Now when user click on download button , downloading (background) activity with notification progressbar starts. But I want to restrict 2nd download of the same thing. ! what could i do ?